# Is there a name for a mesh has 4 vertices that is not flat

Tags: modeling, topology

Is this good to keep or should i avoid them?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This is called non-planar geometry. I'm sure someone will post a full answer, but in the meantime, you can read what [Autodesk has to say about it](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Polygons-overview-Planar-and-nonplanar-polygons-htm.html)

Comment: Hi. Your question title seems to be asking something different from your question content.

Answer (score -1):

For animation you should avoid such mesh, but if the mesh wouldn't be animated you could over look it. I don't know the name of such mesh for now but i will research on that.